# Bitwise operations in OPenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL ES and I am using the OpenGL ES 2.0 version. Can I use bit-wise operations(right shift,left shift) in fragment shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 does not have bitwise operators. ES 3.0+ do, of course.